# PHP opencart query out data

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

```
                                     <div class="separator clear-left">
                                         <p class="btn-add">
                                             <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a></p>
                                             <p class="btn-details">
                                         <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="" class="hidden-sm">More details</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                                         </div>
                                                 </div>
                                         </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <?php
                                 if ($counter == 8) {
                                         break;
                                 }

                         }

                     }
                 }
                 ?>
         </div>
 </div>
 <?php
```

}

The above code is part of my whole page. There is a problem about that is that when i using

```
        foreach($result2   as $row2){

         }
```

The page load without any problem , but it loop the same data, and if i change the follow code to

```
$row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
```

The whole page stopped working .(code error)

So what should i change about it ?

> after edited , the page is showing all product now instead of 8
>   product

Comment: 1. Your query result will be exhausted on the first iteration in the first loop. 2. What is `$st` and `$en`? 3. You iterate over your query result without doing anything (the  `foreach` loop has no content). 4. What is `$rowcount`?

Comment: bind your printing code inside the `foreach` loop. your are trying to access the `$row2` variable but it is only be accessible in `foreach` loop or you can use `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your printing code inside the `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($result2 as $row2){
    $counter++;
    if($counter =< 8){
      continue;
    }
    ?> // closing php tag 
          <div class="col-sm-3">
             <div class="col-item">
                <div class="photo">
                   <img src="/image/<?php echo $row2['image']; ?>" class="img- 
                                                     responsive" alt="a"/>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
             <div class="row">
           <div class="price col-md-6">
           <h5>
           <?php echo $row2['name'];?>
          <?php 
           $counter++;}
          ?> //Closing the php tag and foreach loop
```

Comment: after i did that , somehow that my page is showing all product . i have uploaded a full code in my first post

Comment: After tried your codes still the same problem , i wondered that where did i do wrong .

Comment: For explanation `foreach` loop , through all database table's row and in your first row your foreach loop through all row but at last loop step the last data is saved in $row2 variable and you are printing them

Comment: @greenboxgoolu if you are trying to fetch only 8 product then there is two ways to do that one the with query and second is using for loop

Comment: Well , actually for the page there is 2 "Slide" using carousel .

I managed to do it the first slide (which is 8 product ) , but i have problem on the 2nd slide (which is i'm unable to fetch another 8 product )

Comment: so you want to fetch only 8 products or only 8th product

Comment: 8 Product
(2 Slide) 
1st Slide ( 1st-8th Product ) 
2nd Slide ( 9th-16th Product)

Comment: Edited only print 8 products

Comment: Based on the code , the 2nd slide of the carousel work fine (8 product) but it start from 1st Product , i need it to start on 9th product

Comment: So you want to start products from 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205208/discussion-between-greenboxgoolu-and-ahmed-says-reinstate-monica).